# How to limit limit the users input in an edittext to everything but numbers

Tags: android, android-edittext

I would like to know how to stop the user from inputting numbers into my edittext programmatically, so that it has a similar effect as doing this would

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ#$%......"
```

I have looked at `edittext.setInputType(InputType.something)` but I could not find an input type which stops the user inputting numbers.

Does anyone know how I can do this either through an input type or some other method?

Comment: Have a look at `InputFilter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        String output = "";
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(source.charAt(i))) { 
                    output += source.charAt(i); 
            }
        } 
        return output;
    } 
}; 
edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

assume edit is your EditText

Comment: This almost works, there is a slight problem that I can't figure out however... when I type a number, the entire contents of the edittext field dissapears. Do you know how I could fix that?

Comment: @jcw fixed, my mistake, sorry.

Comment: @jcw, also I want to tell you, that I found a bug. If you try remove symbol, this filter will copy and paste all contents twice

Comment: I found a way to fix them, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType you can use

```
number - A numeric only field. Corresponds to TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL.
```

Have you tried:

```
edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this accomplishes the opposite of what OP wants, which is to allow everything _except_ numbers.

Answer (score 0):

pavki_a's answer worked perfectly, but there were just a few bugs with the backspace and with the word suggestion. I fixed those by adding :

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

This might be a problem if you want auto correct, but for me it worked fine